# Specific ways of opening a window

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference, phrasal-verbs

As far as I know, `to open a window` simply means to `move the respective sash away, so that air may blow through` (yeah, I know it's a clumsy defintiton).

- Is there a specific verb which would describe opening a window in the way the first window (from left) in the image is opened? My intuition is `to tilt out`, but I have never seen it used in this way
- Similarly, is there a specific verb describing the way the second window in the image is open?

[image: windows comparison]

Comment: To "swing the window open", maybe?  [Saying that someone "swung the window open/closed/wide" is reasonably common.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="swung+the+window")

Comment: @stangdon: Does `swinging` the window result into window being open in tilt position?

Comment: Well, *to swing* just means ["to move or cause to move back and forth or from side to side while suspended or on an axis."](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+swing)  So you could swing it open, which would result in it being open (whatever position that would mean for that particular window), or swing it closed, which would result in it being closed.

Comment: @stangdon: I was asking how do I, for instance, ask someone to open a window in a way, that would result into window being tilt, specifically.

Comment: I don't think we have a specific word for that.  Just saying "open the window" usually means "open the window in whatever way that particular window opens."  I mean, most windows only open one way, so it's not like you usually have to specify it!  But *tilt* is a verb, so it would sound reasonable enough to say "tilt the window open" if you have to be specific.

Comment: You can say, for any of the three windows, or a car window, *Crack the window*, which means to open the window just a bit.  See [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Crack&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) verb, transitive, definition 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it hard to imagine a situation where you would need to specify the way to open different types of windows. Well, If that doesn't matter, simply say "close/open the window(s)."

But if you are, say, teaching young kids to open the windows, then you might really need to describe the way you open a specific type of window.

For the first type of window, say "tilt" or "tilt inward/outward."

For the second type of window, say "swing."

For the Third type of window, say "slide vertically/horizontally"